# jQuery ajax always throws error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I build a page for mobiles, but i have problem when i send a POST with jQuery.ajax on my phone. It's works on my PC but not on my phone.

I have this code when i make the post request:

```
        window.jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Action/PageHandler.ashx?do=" + method,
            cache: false,
            data : postFormData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                DataHandler.GetResult(data, callBack);
            },
            error: function (oXhr, status, msg) {
                callBack(false, msg);
            }
        });
```

The response when i use my phone is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
Date: Wed, 25 Dec 2013 17:20:00 GMT
p3p: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 69

{"ErrorMessage":"Wrong pasword or username!"}
```

When i run this code on my phone, the error function is called, status = error and msg is empty. I use jQuery mobile.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you change the useragent/screen resolution in your PC browser and see if you can emulate the same error?

Comment: When i change the useragent to iPhone 3.0 in firefox on my pc, and it's works perfect.
But when i try Electric Mobile Studio 2012, both iPhone and iPad has problem.